# How to pinpoint different locations to my MapView on Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, dictionary, mapactivity

I'm currently developing an Android Studio application, which has a Map Activity.
The purpose of that map activity is to pinpoint some key locations (e.g. cafes) that are close to the user's location.

Example: User A opens the app, clicks on the button that redirects them to the Map Activity. Now that the map is open, they're able to see all the cafes near them without having to search.

My Map Activity already pinpoints to the user's current location, but I wasn't able to find anything about pinpointing specific locations near the user.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I did work on a project similar to what you asked here using google place API / google maps.

[Here is the Github link of the project](https://github.com/rpadma/EAT-AT-SFO)

Let me know if that helped you or if you have any more questions :)